# SQL Exception: A result set was generated for update

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

We are using Hibernate to interact with and update an SQL Server. We are currently writing to two tables (only one successfully) but are not able to update one of them due to the following error:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:126 - could not execute statement [n/a] | com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.
```

We also get the warning:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:137 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
```

The strange thing is that we use the exact same code to update the other table (and this succeeds). And we've triple checked that we have the correct mapping from the Java object to the SQL table. Additionally, we are able to update the table that has the issue when running an update command from the Console. So it appears that something is wrong with Hibernate or at least how Hibernate is interacting with the DB.

Here is the code where we commit to the DB (each section is a different level in the call stack... starts from top and goes to bottom):

```
// Call from Business Logic
flowAssignmentDao.saveOrUpdate(flowAssignmentEntity);
```

```
// Class that wraps hibernateUtility
public abstract class BaseDao<E> {
    protected final HibernateUtility hibernateUtility;
    public void saveOrUpdate(E entity) {
        hibernateUtility.saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
}
```

```
// Class/Method that actually commits to DB
    @Synchronized
    public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity) {
        try {
            this.startTransaction();
            this.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
            this.commit(); // Error occurs here!!!
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            this.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know where might be a good place to start debugging this? These error statements are not very helpful.

Comment: Check for triggers on the problem table.

Comment: Increase logging, check database logs, etc.

Comment: You probably have trigger(s) that don't include `SET NOCOUNT ON` as their first statement.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The issue was a trigger on the problem table. There was an SQL syntax error that was failing after each update attempt.